# ImportError when configuring python's logging module with a dict and custom handler

Tags: python, logging, flask, python-3.5

I've written a custom logging handler for python's logging package.  This handler may or may not work, but this is beyond the scope of the question.

I'm trying to specify the handler using a configuration dict.  However the logging package seems to be unable to find the correct class.  This is the relevant section of my config dict:

```
"file": {
    "class": "iis.logging.LockingFileHandler",
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Which is defined in a file `configuration/development.py`.  It is imported and passed to `logging.config.dictConfig` in a file `iis/__init__.py`.  `LockingFileHandler` is defined in a file `iis/logging.py`.  Both `configuration` and `iis` are in my path.

When I run flask (which imports `iis/__init__`, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 384, in resolve
    self.importer(used)
ImportError: No module named 'iis.logging.LockingFileHandler'; 'iis.logging' is not a package
```

Followed by a bunch of exceptions caused by this one.  I suspect that I am mising some trick here.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in the `iis/logging` directory?

Comment: @S.deMelo  There is no `iis/logging` directory.  LockingFileHandler is defined in `iis/logging.py`

Comment: Yes, sorry.  The error message is strange then, because it seems to consider 'iis.logging.LockingFileHandler' as a module.

Comment: @S.deMelo For the record I tried to put `LockingFileHandler` in `iis/logging/handlers.py`, but that just moves the problem one level down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think I well victim to Python's confusing(!) import sematics.  The module `iis.logging` was shaddowing the global `logging` module (somehow).  Renaming to `iss.log` did the trick.